# .htaccess rewrite to root file of same name if no matching subdir

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

How would I write my htaccess to look for a file of the same name as a non-existent sub-directory?  For instance, if I head to **example.com/about** and there is no 'about' sub-dir, I want to rewrite (not redirect) to the file **example.com/about.html** (and of course, keeping the URL as typed).  In other words, is there a sub-dir of the requested name?  If not, is there a file in the root of the same name?  If yes, serve it up; if not, proceed to the usual 404.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the MultiViews option as specified [here](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/rewrite/).

You should just have to set it like this:

```
<Directory /home/www/sitename/htdocs>
Options + MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks David, that is the perfect solution. If applying the Option to the whole site, just leave off the <Directory> altogether; i.e. add "Options +MultiViews" to the .htaccess in the website's root.